# Opening a new browser window via JQuery not sending all values missing data

Tags: javascript, jquery

Having a issue with windows.open();

Framework :Asp.netMVC
Code:C#,Razor
Issue :jquery
When the function trigger it should send parameters to the controller Actioid and taskid but I am having an issue it just sending Actioid and taskid 
 is null. when i debug it on the client side it is showing all parameters have values but when it calls action result it just sending one parameter.

```
window.open('@Url.Action("Test", "Search")?taskid=' + model.id + '&actionid=' + model.name +',popUpWindow, height=750, width=960, left=300, top=100, resizable=yes, scrollbars=yes, toolbar=yes, menubar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=yes');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
window.open('@Url.Action("Test", "Search")?taskid=' + model.id + '&actionid=' + model.name ,'popUpWindow, height=750, width=960, left=300, top=100, resizable=yes, scrollbars=yes, toolbar=yes, menubar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=yes');
```

i missed **","** before popupwindow